# Padding won't fill the <li> and <div> interly

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I am trying to create a simple menu bar with 40px of height and fill 80% of the browser width.

The problem here is that I am trying to center the text, but when looking at it using different colors (one for the div, another for the ul, and another for the li), I see a small pixel not filled by the padding of the `<a>`.

The only solution to fill it is to make the padding at 10.35px instead of 10px or 11px.

The HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>myWebSite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head> 
  <body>
      <div id="menu">
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com">Hello</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS :

```
body, html {
    width               : 100%;
    margin              : 0;
}

#menu {
    background-color    : black;
    width               : 100%;
    height              : 40px;
}

ul {
    list-style          : none;
    height              : 100%; 
    background-color    : yellowgreen;
}

li {
    margin              : 0;
    padding             : 0;
    float               : left;
    line-height         : 40px; 
    background-color    : blue;
}

a {
    margin              : 0;
    text-decoration     : none;
    color               : white;
    font-weight         : bold;
    padding             : 10px 5px;
    background-color    : blueviolet; 
}

a:hover {
    background-color    : orange;
}
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happening and what better solution should I use to do this ?

Comment: Change your line-height to 39px instead of 40px.

Comment: as additional to all answers: when you set percent value of something like width and height, you must remember what browser finaly work with pixel. so if you want 50% width of 11px element, some browser will make it 5px and some will make it with 6px. This also can be seen if you zoom the window

Answer (score 1):

add `display:block` to `a` element and then take off the vertical padding.
http://jsfiddle.net/L8dpB/

Answer (score 1):

By forcing the < a> tags to display as a block level element they will fill their container.

In this case I've also commented out the padding to stop and overflow outside the < li> elements.

```
a {
    display: block;
    /*padding             : 10px 5px;*/

    margin              : 0;
    text-decoration     : none;
    color               : white;
    font-weight         : bold;
    background-color    : blueviolet; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top and bottom padding on your links and use this CSS:

```
a {
    margin : 0;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : white;
    font-weight : bold;
    padding : 0px 5px;
    background-color : blueviolet;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Yt38y/)**

Answer (score 0):

first of all I think you're setting a lot of unnecessary background colors. May I suggest you set the right ones? If I understood what you want, just set them for the `div` `#menu` and for the links (`<a>`).

Now your problem is that **you forgot to set your links as blocks**. Use `display: block` for them. Do that and adjust the paddings correctly. Thus there is no need to set the  `line-height` for the list items.

As a tip of best practices, don't set the `height` for the `<ul>`. Use a [clearfix method](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to naturally fit the height of its child elements.

As a diagnosis for your code, a final advice is, there is no need to set `margin` and `padding` for `<li>` and `margin` for `<a>`.